# Getting image from server asynchronously in android?

Tags: android

I have 400 images in my server database. I am able to get those images and display in my emulator. But it is taking lot of time to get the image from server. Hence I want to get the image asynchronously. How can I achieve that task? Help me regarding this...Will be thankful in advance....

I want to convert the following code to asynchronous task....

My Code:

```
public View getView(.......)
{
ImageView myimgview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView100);
drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(v.getTag().toString());
myimgview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
---
---
---
}

private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
try {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "image.png");
    return d;
    }
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a thread in combination with a handler:

```
public void setImageInThread(final ImageView imageView, final String url) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            Drawable result = (Drawable) message.obj;
            imageView.setImageDrawable(result);
        }
    };

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable(url);
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage(1, drawable);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Where getDrawable is your function to get images synchronously.

Comment: This is asynchronously. What I mean is that the function "getDrawable(url)" is the (synchronous) function which you currently have. Since it's executed in a Thread it will be executed asynchronously.

Comment: Or just forget I said "synchronously". This will be executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is use asynchronous task in java

hear some example

```
    private class DownloadImages AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    //use your async task hear 
    //in your case call LoadImageFromWebOperations(urls[0])
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
}
```

And call this async task by passing requied image url

```
    DownloadImages task = new DownloadImages ();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://your image url.com" });
```

Hear is good tutorial for this

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask

Answer (score 0):

I use [Prime](https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime) for all of my image loading, it can take care of this easily.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If i want to show progress bar how can i do that?